# Apache httpd.pid file always contains the wrong pid

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, apache-2.4

We just upgraded Apache from 2.2 to 2.4.  One of the initial problems I'm seeing is the httpd.pid file is always wrong.

```
admin@vm:/etc/apache2$ apachectl start
admin@vm:/etc/apache2$ ps -ef | grep httpd
admin    28601     1  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin//httpd -k start
admin    28602 28601  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin//httpd -k start
admin    28603 28601  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin//httpd -k start
admin    28604 28601  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin//httpd -k start
admin    28605 28601  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin//httpd -k start
admin    28606 28601  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin//httpd -k start
admin    28607 28601  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin//httpd -k start
admin    28608 28601  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin//httpd -k start
admin    28609 28601  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin//httpd -k start
admin    28619 10867  0 09:11 pts/0    00:00:00 grep httpd
admin@vm:/etc/apache2$ cat /var/log/apache2/logs/httpd.pid 
6889127571385
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Also, could this potentially cause any problems with Apache?  I understand stopping Apache will fail.  But besides that, could this cause any other issues?

Comment: How did you do this? Compiling Apache from the source? What distro you use? Please be more specific.

Comment: Building version 2.4.9 from source.  OS is WindRiver Linux, version 5.0.1.13.